# How do I access specific values in my xml?

Tags: php, xml

Let's assume I have simple XML, such as:

```
<people>
    <person id="52">
        <name>John</name>
    </person>
    <person id="53">
        <name>Sally</name>
    </person>
</people>
```

I use `$xml=simplexml_load_file('filename')` to load the file.

How do I reference the name of person with id 53, without iterating through looking for the person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to search for the matching element.

```
$person = $xml->xpath("/people/person[@id='53']")[0];
```

Comment: thanks, I had to drop the [0] at the end, and then refer to it as :
  $person[0]->name

Comment: PHP 5.4 adds the ability to subscript after a function call.